# how do i make a array with lots of places in c?

Tags: c, sieve

I'm making the sieve of erasthostenes in c. I have programmed it in other languages before but I never encountered this problem. Here's my algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>  
#include <limits.h>   
     
int main(){
    clock_t t;
    t = clock();

    int n = 1299710;
    
    bool pPrimes[n];
    
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        pPrimes[i] = true;
    }
    
    pPrimes[0] = false;
    pPrimes[1] = false;

    for(int i = 2; i<sqrt(n); i++){
        if(pPrimes[i]){
            for(int x = i*i; x<n; x+=i){
                pPrimes[x] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 2; i<n; i++){
        if (pPrimes[i]){
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
    t = clock() - t;
    double time_taken = ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
 
    printf("%f", time_taken);

    return 0;
}
```

It's when I declare `pPrimes` that `n` can't be large enough. A million or so works but not more. Is there anyway of fixing this?

I tried debugging but I only get this error message:

> line 1:  4320 Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: Your stack memory is a limited resource. Putting such a large array on the stack is likely to overflow: `bool pPrimes[n];`. As you have a hard coded size, you don't need a VLA but could make it a static array in that function. Or move it out of the function and make it global. Or you could use dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: You should look at [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). You only need an array for the number of primes you want to find, not all the numbers up to the largest prime number.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks! I have basically only coded in python up until now so what youre saying doesn't really make sense to me:). How to i make it a static array?

Comment: You make it `static bool pPrimes[SIZE];` with `SIZE` being a constand expression, not a variable. And to fix that "doesn't make sense" you read any C tutorial or text book and check sections about local variables. Or search for "static variables" etc.

Comment: @Gerhardh thanks! I just dont understand how i can replace n with SIZE. Do i not need to define SIZE to make sure the variable is as big as n?

Comment: You make `#define SIZE 1299710` or some other large number. But as I mentioned: if you implement that sieve algorithm, you won't need such a large array as with your current approach because you don't need to store the non-primes.

Comment: You only need to check for dividability by up to square root of N (maybe plus one) to check N for prime. That reduces the size of needed array most. How to use an array which only stores primes is not quite clear to me. The ideas I have how to do that are inefficient. @Gerhardh Please elaborate.

Comment: You only store each prime you have found so far in an array. For each new number you only need to check if you can divide by the primes you have stored in that array. If you checked for all numbers in the array and could not divide without remainder, then you found a new prime and store it in the array. Then continue with next odd number and check against all values from that array.

Comment: @Yunnosch it seems the OP does not want to check if `n` is prime but to find all primes up to `n`.

Comment: @Gerhardh Checking anything lower than N will also not need more than square root of N entries in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

**Out of local space**

OP reports with large `n`, there is trouble. Better to allocate with `malloc()`.

`bool` is not certainly the narrowest type - use `unsigned char`.  Better to allocate with an *unsigned size* such as `unsigned` or `size_t`.

```
 //int n = 1299710;
 //bool pPrimes[n];

 unsigned n = 1299710;

 if (n < 2) {  // Avoid edge cases
   fprintf(stderr, "Use larger value, not %u\n", n);
   return EXIT_FAILURE;
 }

 unsigned char *pPrimes = malloc(sizeof *nPrimes * n);
 if (pPrimes == NULL) {
   fprintf(stderr, "Out-of-memory %u\n", n);
   return EXIT_FAILURE;
 }
```

**Off by one**

I would expect `int n = 1299710;` to imply finding all the primes up to *and including* `n`.

```
unsigned char *pPrimes = malloc(sizeof *nPrimes * (n+1));

// for(int i = 2; i<n; i++){
for(unsigned i = 2; i <= n; i++){  // <=
```

Referencing this [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Pseudocode), edge tests are off by one.
Do not trust a raw `sqrt()` for an integer problem.  When the expected result is x.00000..., that function may return x_minus_1.99999....

```
unsigned qsrt_n = lround(sqrt(n));
// for(int i = 2; i<sqrt(n); i++){
for(unsigned i = 2; i <= sqrt_n; i++){  // <=
    if(pPrimes[i]){
        // for(int x = i*i; x<n; x+=i){
        for(unsigned x = i*i; x <= n; x+=i){  // <=
            pPrimes[x] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating too much memory in the stack. This is known as a [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

Either (as [@Gerhardh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782754/gerhardh) said in a comment):

1. Use a `static` array
2. Use a global array
3. Use `malloc()`

---

##### 1. With a `static` array:

```
int main(void)
{
    #define n 1299710
    static bool primes[n] = {false, false};

    for (size_t i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
        primes[i] = true;
    }
    
    long srn = sqrt(n) + 1;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < srn; ++i) {
        if (!primes[i]) continue;
        
        for (size_t ii = i*i; ii < n; ii += i)
            primes[ii] = false;
    }
    // print...
}
```

---

##### 2. With a global array:

```
#define n 1299710
/*static?*/ bool primes[n] = {false, false};

int main(void)
{
    for (size_t i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
        primes[i] = true;
    }

    long srn = sqrt(n) + 1;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < srn; ++i) {
        if (!primes[i]) continue;
        
        for (size_t ii = i*i; ii < n; ii += i)
            primes[ii] = false;
    }
    
    // print...
}
```

---

##### 3. With a dynamic array:

```
int main(void)
{
    const size_t n = 1299710;
    bool *primes = malloc(n * sizeof bool);
    
    if (!primes) {
        printf("Memory issues. Goodbye!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    for (size_t i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
        primes[i] = true;
    }
    
    primes[0] = false;
    primes[1] = false;

    long srn = n == 1 ? 1 : sqrt(n) + 1;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < srn; ++i) {
        if (!primes[i]) continue;
        
        for (size_t ii = i*i; ii < n; ii += i)
            primes[ii] = false;
    }
    
    // print...
}
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Maybe enforcing `n > 2` is the way to go, since the entire algorithm doesn't make any sense for `n <= 1`.

Comment: Certain `for (size_t i = 0; i < srn; ++i) {` still looks amiss.  I'd expect `for (size_t i = 0; i <= srn; ++i) {`.